# ps aux | grep returns pid for itself too

Tags: bash, pid, ps

I am using this command to get the process ID of another command:

```
ps aux | grep 7000.conf | awk '{print $2}'
```

This will return two PIDs:

```
7731
22125
```

I only want the first one. The second is the PID for `grep` in the above command. Thanks in advance to any one who knows how to alter the above command to return just the first pid.

p.s. open to a new command that does the same thing

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In this particular case, escaping the `.` to what I assume it was meant to do should work:

```
ps aux | grep '7000\.conf' | awk '{print $2}'
```

Alternatively, exclude `grep`:

```
ps aux | grep 7000.conf | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: Is not easier to use just `ps aux | grep -v '7000.conf'`. No need for double grep nor awk. -v just does "remove myself from result when doing grep".

Comment: @erm3nda: `-v` means “invert the match”, so that will not find what you’re looking for in the first place with `7000.conf` – it’ll find every other process. `awk` is also part of the original question and unrelated to removing `grep` (it extracts the pid from the row). So, no.

Answer (score 5):

`ps aux | grep "[7]000.conf"` will work as well.